# Join one table against many rows in another table

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a localized table where I store all the localized content for my MySQL database.  I am trying to write a query that will retrieve, for a given table with multiple columns, all of the localized content for those columns.  Probably easier to understand with an example:

**foo**

```
code    title    localized_title_code    description    localized_description_code
A001    Bar1     foo_A001_title          Baz1           foo_A001_description
A002    Bar2     foo_A002_title          Baz2           foo_A002_description
```

**localization**

```
id    code                  value    locale
1     foo_A001_title        Bar1o    es
2     foo_A002_title        Bar2o    es
3     foo_A001_description  Baz1o    es
4     foo_A002_description  Baz2o    es
```

I want something like this:

```
code title localized_title description localized_description
A001 Bar1  Bar1o           Baz1        Baz1o
A002 Bar2  Bar2o           Baz2        Baz2o
```

I know I can easily get this with two queries with something like:

```
select foo.title,//Or description
    localization.value as localized_title
from foo
join localization
where localization.code = concat('foo', foo.code, 'title')
and localization.locale = 'es';
```

but is there a way to get both of the localized columns into one result?  It is safe to assume that there will be no missing entries (ie if there is a title, there is a description).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
select foo.code,
    foo.title,
    title.value as localized_title,
    foo.description,
    description.value as localized_description
from foo
join localization as title on title.code = concat('foo', foo.code, 'title')
    and title.locale = 'es'
join localization as description on description.code = concat('foo', foo.code, 'description')
    and description.locale = 'es'
```

Comment: Sorry, I am writing this query in sql2005